# Doesn't vs don't

Tags: verb-agreement

What's correct here:

> The body language of South Africans doesn't seem right.

or

> The body language of South Africans don't seem right.

Please explain. Because the first one hears right. But grammar says for third person (plural) use don't.

Comment: Sounds like a choice between 'does not' and 'do not', which is a straightforward question of singular or plural. Since the 'body language of South Africans' is singular the correct form is *doesn't sound right*.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably confusing you because the subject is the body language (singular) of South Africans (plural). You should change it to "South African body language doesn't seem right".

Comment: I agree with Gabe.

Comment: There is no object in the sentence. _The body language of South Africans_ is the subject, not the object.

Answer (score 1):

*Of South Africans* is a prepositional phrase and is disregarded when conjugating the verb. The subject of the sentence is *body language*, which is singular. Therefore, *doesn't* is the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused here - are you under the impression that *doesn't* and *don't* are the same words?

They are themselves contractions of *different conjugations* of the same word.

**DOESN'T** is a contraction of **DOES NOT**.

**DON'T** is a contraction of **DO NOT**.

The reason that:

> The body language of South Africans **don't** seem right.

'feels off' is because, at its base, what you're *actually* saying is:

> The body language of South Africans **do not** seem right.

You need to match conjugation to subject. A singular third-party pronoun such as 'The body language' requires conjugation as such.

Does that help clear it up?

Answer (score -1):

as far as I can see that the **point** (**phrase - word order**) of speaking is body **language** which is **singular**, not the Africans. Therefore, [doesn't] is used here.